# Which method of returning a view is the best performance wise?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What is the best method of returning a view to the Controller Action? in terms of performance, ease of testing, optimisation etc.

```
return View();
```

or

```
return View("[ActionName]");
```

and then

```
return View([model]);
```

vs

```
return View("[ActionName]",[model]);
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't an advice forum. What are you trying to accomplish here? As with anything to do with performance, test it yourself. Profile your code to see if there's any significant difference.

Comment: I *really* doubt there's much of any difference.

Comment: Even if there was any difference, the difference would be a few magnitude smaller that the total request execution time. Use the simplest overload you need.

Comment: As @Phil1970 said, the simplest overload, and that would be return View();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've run a little benchmark and this is what I'm getting:

```
    readonly Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    public void Benchmark()
    {
        var t1 = Test(View);
        var t2 = Test(() => View("[ActionName]"));
        var t4 = Test(() => View(new Model()));
        var t3 = Test(() => View("[ActionName]", new Model()));

        string result = $"{t1} - {t2} - {t3} - {t4}";
        //Results:
        //4466 - 4856 - 6969 - 6977
        //4551 - 4986 - 7070 - 7056
        //5181 - 5263 - 7142 - 7864

    }

    public long Test(Func<ViewResult> f)
    {
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        { var x = f(); }

        sw.Stop();
        long t = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        sw.Reset();
        return t;
    }
```

So the first two seem a little bit faster... However, the difference is insignificant. Use whatever method works best for you.